# I m getting this error, i run my react native using expo

Tags: reactjs, native

While trying to resolve module `idb` from file `

`C:\Users\chouk\OneDrive\Bureau\my-app\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js`

, the package `C:\Users\chouk\OneDrive\Bureau\my-app\node_modules\idb\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\chouk\OneDrive\Bureau\my-app\node_modules\idb\build\index.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `C:\Users\chouk\OneDrive\Bureau\my-app\node_modules\idb\build\index.cjs(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `C:\Users\chouk\OneDrive\Bureau\my-app\node_modules\idb\build\index.cjs\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)`

Comment: Just restart the bundler, and try again

Comment: I restart the bundler, but i get the same problem, when i remove this line :            
 import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail} from "firebase/auth"; i get no error.

Comment: Try to remove and add the firebase package again with `npm` or `yarn`.

Comment: solved the my  issue with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179070/react-native-bundling-failure-error-message-while-trying-to-resolve-module-i

Answer (score 0):

I hit this exact issue and "fixed" it by downgrading the `firebase` dependency to `9.7.0` (it was previously `9.8.1`)

You can do that by editing the `firebase` entry in the `dependencies` section of `package.json` to be `"9.7.0"`