# React-native bundling failure. ERROR MESSAGE: "While trying to resolve module 'idb'..... Indeed none of these files exist":

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, indexeddb

**ERROR MESSAGE IN QUESTION:**

While trying to resolve module `idb` from file `C:\Users\OG\Desktop\programming\react_native\mealstogo\MealsToGo2\node_modules\@firebase\app\dist\esm\index.esm2017.js`, the package `C:\Users\OG\Desktop\programming\react_native\mealstogo\MealsToGo2\node_modules\idb\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Users\OG\Desktop\programming\react_native\mealstogo\MealsToGo2\node_modules\idb\build\index.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

[Error message photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3lcu.png)

The confusing part of this error is that the file index.esm2017 does in fact exist at the directory. '`C:\Users\OG\Desktop\programming\react_native\mealstogo\MealsToGo2\node_modules\idb\build\index.cjs'

I have uninstalled and reinstalled firebase. I have installed and uninstalled 'idb'.  I have cleared yarn cache, expo cache, deleted node_modules and reinstalled as well as cleared watchman cache all to no avail. I have also triple checked that the file directory is in fact where the error message says it isn't.

The error arose when expo installing lottie-react-native, however it seems unrelated, and the problem remained once removing lottie-react-native. I have used git to revert my code to before the behavior started and now the problem persists here as well.

It almost seems as the entire project is now trashed, how do I move forward.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you are using expo, to resolve this issue, create a **metro.config.js** file in the project root. In the file add the file extension `cjs`. [details](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts)

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSr4.png)

React Native cli

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
const { resolver: defaultResolver } = getDefaultConfig.getDefaultValues();
exports.resolver = {
  ...defaultResolver,
  sourceExts: [
    ...defaultResolver.sourceExts,
    "cjs",
  ],
};
```

Comment: @Sohel So is the issue in fact with expo and not firebase?

Comment: @JohnyClash Actually, firebase use `.cjs` file extension which isn't supported in expo or in react native by default. So we need to manually configure the `metro.config` to parse it. [Please read the details here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts)

Comment: Related metro issue: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/535

Comment: FYI I had to reinstall `node_modules` afterwards before it finally worked

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks. React Native project, so I just pasted the 2nd code segment into a new file at root called metro.config.js

Comment: When I try this `getDefaultConfig` is undefined when metro boots. But if I follow the require down into the module and it all seems to be there and exported as one would expect. I have an ejected project. I used the hardcoded solution from EdEd for now, but I'd rather a more dynamic "add to the defaults" approach like this.

Answer (score 35):

I get the same error... I think there's something funny about the new firebase version. I downgraded my firebase version to 9.6.11 to fix the issue temporarily...

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@9.6.11
```

Comment: worked for me with react-native-cli and with yarn, but remember if on iOS doing npx pod-install ios

Comment: i had to downgrade from v9.12 to this. thank you!

Answer (score 32):

I just added the following code to `metro.config.js` file. Im using Firebase v9.8.1

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  //added this
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
};
```

Comment: This fixed the error for me and was the only method that works because `getDefaultConfig` is undefined when metro boots for some reason. But I noticed my defaults in `node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/defaults.js` are `["js", "json", "ts", "tsx"]` so I made it `["js", "json", "ts", "tsx", "cjs"]`

Comment: This is similar to what I did but `sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'cjs']` is even cleaner because you just read the existing ones and add `cjs` for firestore

Answer (score 5):

I tried few things to resolve this issue in expo the solution worked for me to create **metro.config.js** file in root directory and add the following code;

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

And now restart your expo app!!

Answer (score 2):

Found this that worked after restarting metro bundler:
https://github.com/thysultan/stylis/issues/233

For Expo you have to change your app.json file:

```
{
  "expo": {
    ..., 
    "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": ["cjs"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed this command it will automatically downgrade your firebase version and resolve the issue

`expo install firebase@9.6.11`

Answer (score 0):

I have a react-native project(no expo) and got the same error, in my case I had firebase 9.7.0, but I changed to 9.6.11 like the buddy upper in this thread and it works.
I build node modules with yarn install, and after npx pod-install.
this is my package.json after and before(just firebase changed)

after:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"firebase": "9.7.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
```

},

before: (it works):

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"firebase": "9.6.11",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.13.1"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

After 1 hour research I found my solution. I got this error because wrong `authDomain` in firebase config.

Old:

`authDomain: "https://something.firebaseio.com"`

Fix:

`authDomain: "something.firebaseio.com"`

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is **not** an efficient or recommended fix. Just quick and dirty.*

If you keep running into the issue and need a short-term fix then you can navigate over to the `idb` folder inside your `node_modules` folder, access the `package.json` file and change any file type ending in `cjs` to `js`.

```
node_modules --> idb --> package.json --> change any 'cjs' to 'js'
```

Again, this **isn't** the best solution. It's just a duct tape fix.

Answer (score -1):

Having the exact same issue even after adding firebase in a clean expo project. The issue is due to .cjs not supported in expo.

I fixed it
by adding cjs into metro.config.js as described here: https://github.com/thysultan/stylis/issues/233#issuecomment-1000648356

Comment: The last thing I tried was downgrading the firebase version as @crunchtoast suggested. I have not yet experimented and found whether this answer works.

Comment: I did try to add a cjs resolver in the metro.config file but it didn't fix it for me... there was still something up with metro recognizing the files... I think ultimately it's a firebase issue, since they just added idb as a dependency a couple days ago