# firebase-js-sdk v9 doesn't work with react native? Error: While trying to resolve module `idb`

Tags: firebase, react-native, indexeddb

trying to use firebase-js-sdk v9 for my react-native project but app build fails due to the following idb related error.
Does anyone know anything about this issue?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because let's avoid just pasting screenshots of text. Prefer to actually enter in the text so that others can find this through search engines. Do the redaction in the text instead of Microsoft Paint.

Comment: right, totally agree!
I downgraded firebase to v9.6.1 which works fine.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using expo, to resolve this issue, create a **metro.config.js** file in the project root. In the file add the file extension `cjs`. [details](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts)

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSr4.png)

React Native cli

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
const { resolver: defaultResolver } = getDefaultConfig.getDefaultValues();
exports.resolver = {
  ...defaultResolver,
  sourceExts: [
    ...defaultResolver.sourceExts,
    "cjs",
  ],
};
```

Comment: I added this as you said and nothing changed. Is it possible that the problem is in something else?

Comment: @Listopad02 Are you using expo? You can clear the cache by `expo start --android --clear` or try to delete `node_modules` and reinstall packages. It should work.

Comment: This worked for many people, I believe maybe something wrong with your setup.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179070/react-native-bundling-failure-error-message-while-trying-to-resolve-module-i/72201722#72201722

Comment: I found a mistake, i was making bad queries. Now it is OK. Thanks for your answer, it really helped me

Comment: @Listopad02 You are welcome. You can vote for this answer if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I just added the following code to metro.config.js file. Im using Firebase v9.8.1 and React Native CLI

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
  //added this
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded firebase version to v9.6.1 which works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Downgrading to version 9.6.11 solved it for me.

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@9.6.11
```