# react native expo firebase auth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

IM trying to signup an email auth using firebase and Expo but it says an error
[2023-06-27T23:36:31.891Z]  @firebase/app: Firebase: Error thrown when reading from IndexedDB. Original error: (0 , _idb.openDB) is not a function. (app/idb-get).
here is code

```
const handleSignUp = () => {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      // Signed in 
      const user = userCredential.user;
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      // ..
    });}
```

there is a redd line under auth says Argument of type '{ auth: Auth; app: FirebaseApp; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'.
Type '{ auth: Auth; app: FirebaseApp; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Auth': name, config, setPersistence, languageCode, and 10 more
here is my firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  **
};


// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export default { auth ,app};
```

re-installing packages

Comment: [Does that help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201804/14945696)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably making a "bad import". In firebase.js you are doing

`export default { auth ,app};`

and the error says

`Argument of type '{ auth: Auth; app: FirebaseApp; }`

So the `auth` you are giving to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is not an "auth object" but an object with keys "auth" and "app".

To fix the problem, I recommend you to delete the

`export default { auth ,app};` line

and export things singularly:

`export const auth = getAuth(app);`

this way `auth` will be just `auth`.