# Connecting Firestore to Expo-managed React Native App

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm trying to connect Firestore (v 9.6.7) to my app. I'm using web 9 syntax. My code is almost directly from the guides [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-web-mobile-client-library#auth-required).

It looks like:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ...
    authDomain: ...,
    projectId: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId:...,
    appId: ...,
    measurementId: ...
  };
  
  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);
  
  // Read collection from Firestore and print it
  const querySnapshot = getDocs(collection(db, "Users"));
  console.log(querySnapshot);
    

  
  export {
    db
  }
```

The promise returned is:

> Promise {
> "_U": 0,
> "_V": 0,
> "_W": null,
> "_X": null,
> }

What's going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Friend, when I tell you I struggled with this for two straight days, I mean two 8 hour straight days.

The answer is in firebase's source.

First thing you need to do is add a `metro.config.js` file to the root of your project. Inside add the following:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");
const { resolver: defaultResolver } = getDefaultConfig.getDefaultValues();
exports.resolver = {
  ...defaultResolver,
  sourceExts: [
    ...defaultResolver.sourceExts,
    "cjs",
  ],
};
```

This will allow "cjs" source extensions.

Another good way to print your collection from firestore is like so:

```
const db = getFirestore()
const colRef = collection(db, "collection")

getDocs(colRef)
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let collection = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          collection.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
       })
    })
```

This is a nice way to print to the console in a much more friendly way.

Give this a try and see if it works. If it doesn't please comment so I can help further.

I want to tag the original stackoverflow answer for the metro.config.js file because I did not come up with this on my own but I can't find it. If I do I will edit this post with the link for credit.

Edit: found it. [Credit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179070/react-native-bundling-failure-error-message-while-trying-to-resolve-module-i).

Comment: You're the man! Thanks so much, I've spent so much time on this. Quick question though. Why wouldn't something like this work:                                                         
  const q = getDocs(colRef)
  q.forEach((doc) =>{
    console.log(doc.docs.data())
  }) // this errors... is q not equivalent to the snapshot in your code?

Comment: Did everything work?? Just want to make sure :)

Comment: GetDocs returns a promise. I am not a pro so I may be wrong, but I think since it returns a promise you need to do more than just console.log the inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You get promise, you should call the getDocs() with await.

`const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Users"));`